# Align flex items to bottom while animating height

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to make an equalizer animation and would like these lines to animate from the bottom of the containing DIV as opposed to animating from the top like they are now.

```css
.equalizer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 10px;
}

.bar {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  background-color: #36D475;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 1px;
  animation-name: bar-animation;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: .25s;
}

.one {
  animation-delay: .1s;
}

.two {
  animation-delay: -.1s;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

.three {
  animation-delay: -.2s;
  
}

.four {
  animation-delay: -.3s;
}

@keyframes bar-animation {
  from { height: 2px;}
  to { height: 10px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="equalizer">
  <div class="bar one"></div>
  <div class="bar two"></div>
  <div class="bar three"></div>
  <div class="bar four"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using transforms might suffice and be lighter than adjusting the `height` property. The property that will change the orientation is the `transform-origin: 0 100%`. Below the script transforms the bars by scaling from `transform: scaleY(1)` to `transform: scaleY(5)`.

```css
.equalizer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 10px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.bar {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  background-color: #36D475;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 1px;
  animation-name: bar-animation;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: .25s;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.one {
  animation-delay: .1s;
}

.two {
  animation-delay: -.1s;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

.three {
  animation-delay: -.2s;
  
}

.four {
  animation-delay: -.3s;
}

@keyframes bar-animation {
  to {transform: scaleY(5);}
}
```

```html
<div class="equalizer">
  <div class="bar one"></div>
  <div class="bar two"></div>
  <div class="bar three"></div>
  <div class="bar four"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `align-items: flex-end;` in `.equalizer` 
you can also use `align-items: center;`to make them align in center

```css
.equalizer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 10px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.bar {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  background-color: #36D475;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 1px;
  animation-name: bar-animation;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: .25s;
}

.one {
  animation-delay: .1s;
}

.two {
  animation-delay: -.1s;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

.three {
  animation-delay: -.2s;
  
}

.four {
  animation-delay: -.3s;
}

@keyframes bar-animation {
  from { height: 2px;}
  to { height: 10px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="equalizer">
  <div class="bar one"></div>
  <div class="bar two"></div>
  <div class="bar three"></div>
  <div class="bar four"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. All you have to do is add `align-items: flex-end;` to your `.equalizer` class. This will align all the bars to the bottom of the div making it start from the bottom rather than from the top. The other solution is you can use `transform: scaleY(-1);` which will flip the whole thing upside down.

```css
.equalizer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 10px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.bar {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  background-color: #36D475;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 1px;
  animation-name: bar-animation;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: .25s;
}

.one {
  animation-delay: .1s;
}

.two {
  animation-delay: -.1s;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

.three {
  animation-delay: -.2s;
  
}

.four {
  animation-delay: -.3s;
}

@keyframes bar-animation {
  from { height: 2px;}
  to { height: 10px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="equalizer">
  <div class="bar one"></div>
  <div class="bar two"></div>
  <div class="bar three"></div>
  <div class="bar four"></div>
</div>
```